# How to prove that a power series cannot be expressed with elementary functions?

Tags: proof-writing, power-series

Suppose that I have an infinite power series with some crazy coefficients.
Suppose also that it is convergent, so everything is "fine".

I'd like to know now the closed-form expression for that function.

Is there any general method of restoring it back to its closed form?
If the function cannot be expressed with some other known functions, how can I *prove* that it is really **impossible** to do so, and not that the solution is **unknown** as of yet?

This always troubles me when I deal with different power series that have a form similar to the power series of some other known function, but somehow there is no known way of expressing it with such known functions:
Is it that simply no one found such a way so far?
Or that it *cannot* be done?
What if it is some crazy expression with trigonometric functions multiplied together and raised to the logarithm of an arctangent, for example? I guess that this would be hard to figure out from the power series back to the functions, but not *impossible*? So how can we be sure that there is *no* such expression possible?

Comment: Do you have a specific example you're interested in?

Comment: No, not really. My question is general, because I encounter many functions like these in my work, e.g. Bessel functions, Legendre functions, Laguerre functions... all those functions with someone's name on it. They usually don't have any other representation except the power series, and I wonder how can we make sure (i.e. prove) that they cannot be expressed simpler.

Comment: But as I said, these are just examples. One can come across all sorts of such crazy power series pretty often when solving differential equations using the power series method.

Comment: when you replace the infinite sum with an integral we get a related problem that has been studied. Search for "diffrential Galois theory", "liouville's theorem" and "Risch algorithm". The name Galois pop's up here because he also asked and studied a similar question: "when can a root of a polynomial equation be expressed as a closed from with radicals." The theories I suggested can be quite difficult to understand and might not answer your question, but the your quesion is of the same kind

Comment: The problem is similar to functions which are not the derivative of any function. It has been proved, for instance, that $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is such a function and the integral has become a new function, SinIntegral. The same with some series: the reciprocal of twin primes is a convergent series whose sum is Brun constant or the reciprocal of cubes, Apery constant. I would like to give my  name $\sin\frac{1}{n^2}$ which converges nobody knows to what. Even $Mathematica$ doesn't know and gives an approximation $1.48352$. After all $\pi$ is the same story a bit more famous :)

Comment: @Raffaele thanks for your examples. I once found an integral too that Wolfram couldn't solve, even if it looked quite simple: $\int \sin(\sin(x)) dx$. Wolfram says: "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions" :P  So yeah, one can find many examples of such functions. But what intrigues me is *when* does that happen and *why*, and how can we *prove* it that this is the case – that it is *impossible* to find the solution, and not just our ignorance of it or lack of mathematical skills.

Comment: @JensRenders thanks for your hints about the Galois theory. These subjects really seem to be related, so I guess I have to read some more about it. Don't be shy to post some stuff about it even if it's "complicated" – even if I don't understand everything now, at least I will know what subjects I have to investigate some more to fill the gaps in my knowledge, and ultimately I should understand it. (There are also other people reading these posts, not just me, and they may find it useful too.)